# Fatal error: Call to a member function getAllOptions() on a non-object in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php on line 434 After Upgrade

Tags: magento

I have upgraded our site from `Magento Version 1.5.1` to `Magento Version 1.7.2`, but I can not access the frontend as well as the Backend also and getting this

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getAllOptions() on a non-object in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php on line 434.
```

I have deleted all the cache files and the session files as well and changed the var folder `permission` from `755` to `777`.

I have deleted all the cache from the database as well.

Please provide me the solution,

Thanks

Comment: make sure your `local.xml` and `config.xml` are in place

Comment: local.xml and config.xml are in the place and there is no problem with it.

Comment: Kalpesh fixed it for me, somebody had removed everything in magento/app/etc/* from version control.  I remembered local.xml but had forgotten about config.xml.  Thanks Kalpesh!

Comment: Kalpesh, that was my issue as well. pulled from repo and forgot about `/app/etc/config.xml`